# How to format any arbitrary float to fit a given display width?

Tags: delphi, formatting

I'm working on a project where a single read-only `TEdit` control displays any arbitrary numeric value, formatted to a particular unit of measurement, so it has also an arbitrary suffix. The width of this edit control is fixed (yet can change based on re-sizing the UI), and I need to make sure whatever number is displayed fits reasonably within this control without overflowing out of view.

Think of it like fitting a mathematical answer on a calculator screen, because that's literally what I'm doing.

Although the complexity of this particular project is much more detailed, let's stick with a simple example which applies to all...

```
function FormattedValue(const ANum: Double; const ASuffix: String; 
  const AWidth: Integer; const DC: HDC): String;
begin
  Result:= FormatFloat('#,###,###,##0.######', ANum) + ASuffix;
  //TODO: How to enforce result to always fit within AWidth pixels?
  //DC = canvas handle of the control where text will be displayed

end;
```

However, I have absolutely no idea how to go about formatting it to fit within `AWidth` constraint, which would be the `TEdit.ClientWidth`. I found `FloatToStrF`, which I'm sure will be needed, but even that has nothing to do with the display area available.

The only way I see so far is to load the font associated with the canvas, and iterate all possible characters, looking for the widest possible character. Then, see how many times the largest character can fit within the given width. Then, use `FloatToStrF` to actually format it, combined with the suffix width. But all that seems like overkill for what seems like a trivial task.

How do I do this, while using scientific notation when necessary?

Comment: What's wrong with using the Canvas.TextWidth of the content and comparing it to the TEdit.ClientWidth, and dropping characters from the right side of the string until it fits?

Comment: @Ken "while using scientific notation when necessary" Result could be a very large whole number, or a very small fraction. Hence "arbitrary". Blindly chopping the string is extremely dangerous, and would destroy the meaning of the actual value.

Comment: OK. Then do what I said above, but don't drop digits. Convert it to scientific notation and compare the width again. You don't have a lot of options here; the edit will fit a max number of characters based on the font size and it's client width, and you have to decide how you're going to reduce the text content until it fits yourself. I gave you a way to measure the size of the content in display pixels and compare it against the edit's content limitations. Deal with shortening the content until it fits however you like. There's no *number formatting magic* that deal with display width.

Comment: @Ken Obviously there's no such thing as magic in programming. Voodoo, sometimes. But no magic. I guess I'm just kinda hoping there's something to make this task easier, considering I'm surely not the first person to need such a thing. Be sure to see my edit too, regarding iterating all characters and calculating the max possible character width. `FloatToStrF` at least allows me to control the number of characters. The suffix might contain characters wider than any of the digits though.

Comment: Numbers know nothing about how they're going to be displayed, and neither do any of the RTL's numeric to string conversion routines. How could they? They know nothing about how or where you're going to display them, and font widths and heights vary widely. You can always add the suffix to the string before calling TextWidth to use the combined length instead, but you're still going to have to decide how to reduce the numeric's representation down to a suitable length yourself.

Comment: As far as *iterate all possible characters*, that's not necessary. Use the entire string to measure with `Canvas.TextWidth(YourStringVariableHere);` to retrieve the entire length of the string, or `Canvas.TextWidth('9');` to get the widest single character size. Numbers aren't as nasty as characters with regard to width variance and don't have ascenders or descenders, so any single digit will work for you.

Comment: @Ken I think you missed the point about the suffix (and potentially prefix too). It could contain characters which are much wider than the standard 0..9 digits. Either way, that part's simple. It's the identifying whether a number should even try to be formatted in scientific notation in the first place which I'm trying to grasp. Depending on the width of the display area, minus the prefix/suffix (again the easy part), I need to identify how to format the number to fit within this given area. If you're doing what I'm doing, you'd understand why it's difficult.

Comment: Further, I'm sure this concept is a very standard thing in the design of calculators. Then again, their digit width is always fixed. But still, there has to be something we're missing that Delphi has to offer that at least takes one step out of this whole process. Kinda like how `FreeAndNil()` turns two lines of code into just one.

Comment: Put prefix on a label near the edit. Put suffix on a label on the other near of the edit (whatever that means). Use a digital font for the edit. Then you'll have a constant number of characters in the edit.

Comment: I didn't miss any point. I've been working on UIs and reports in Delphi since v1 was released, and still do today. I'm well aware of what the built-in support is for numeric formatting in the RTL, and very familiar with what is (and is not) available for displaying those numbers. Your prefix or suffix will be a single fixed width based on the font with which they're being displayed, so no iteration through them is necessary. There's also no iteration through the digits required.

Comment: Prefix/Suffix aside, I can see how no iteration is required here in any case. That was just my initial thought. But I still can't figure out how to use `FloatToStrF` in a way that guarantees it will fit within a given width, while at the same time maximizing accuracy outside of using scientific notation. In other words, I don't want to use scientific notation unless I have to. There's a lot of possible values, large and small, which I need to fit while being as precise as possible.

Comment: I mean, I do understand `AvailableWidth := AWidth - Canvas.TextWidth(APrefix) - Canvas.TextWidth(ASuffix);`. It's using that `AvailableWidth` I'm trying to deal with. Sure, I understand the general idea. Just coding it in the most optimal manner is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: You *can't* do it with FloatToStrF or FormatFloat. Neither of those know anything about displaying output. They convert floating point numbers to strings, period. The solution involves Canvas.TextWidth of the control you're using and deciding how to handle the need to truncate digits until the string fits into the control. There isn't any other alternative, no matter how hard you try to resist it. You can either truncate the digits yourself where you have control of how it's done, or use Round or RoundTo to do it for you, but you're still going to have to do it.

Comment: while (Canvas.TextWidth(Numeric) + Canvas.TextWidth) >= AWidth do` will perform the calculation. Your issue is what to do to reduce the width until the loop exists, which is what I've said from the beginning. What do you do with digits that can't be displayed?

Comment: @Ken Of course `TextWidth` is required here, I'm not doubting that a single bit. Alternatively, `DT_CALCRECT` could be even a better solution. That's an obviously required part of the entire solution. That's not what I'm asking here though. Again, I was hoping there's an existing solution which takes canvas/font/max-width into consideration already, since I'm definitely not the first person to want to fit an arbitrary float value into a minimally available space.  I'm looking for a way to identify whether I need to use `FloatToStrF` in the first place, based on the value of a float.

Comment: There can be no built-in fitting mechanism that alters the string - other than replacing the rightmost part with ellipsis.

Comment: I understand the decreasing number of digits until satisfactory concept. But there's the part before that which identifies the size of the number compared to the available space based on font and font size. The less I have to loop and decrease the number of digits, the more efficient this would be. Because this function needs to be called rapidly upon every user keystroke.

Comment: `DT_CALCRECT` won't improve the performance. You don't need to calculate a rect for output. You already know half of it (the height). You clearly have your mind set on finding a built-in solution that simply does not exist outside what you've already been told, so I give up. Good luck.

Comment: You aren't going to find a built in solution. You need to measure the text. Bisection will be useful. However you say this is an edit control. That implies user input. You can't format the user's input. You have to display what they type as they edit. You say the control is read only. If it is always read only an edit control is the wrong control. A label is usually the appropriate way.

Comment: Personally, it sounds to me like your solution is the wrong one anyway. Use constraints to stop the field becoming too small. Switch to scientific notation once the magnitude of the value reaches a certain size. Then you don't need to use adaptive formatting at all.

Comment: @David It's an edit control to allow the user to select / copy the text. The border is hidden and background same as parent to look like a label, but the user can select the text and copy it.

Comment: Use a static control to.achieve that